# Npm package how to run script programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am building a package that uses an external command tool named plop js. In my `package.json` I want to add a binary that references to an `index.js` file.

```
  "scripts":{
     "plop": "plop"
  },
  "bin": {
    "my-command": "index.js"
  },
```

There is a way to run the `plop` script from my package in the `index.js` file?

My goal is to run this script when the user writes `my-command` in the terminal. (and use the local plop, I want this to be transparent to the consumer)

Comment: Potentially you could just add `require('plop')` to your `index.js` file when you want the command to be called.

Comment: It works but I get the error:  No plopfile found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have the same issue and found this code work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.argv.push('--plopfile', __dirname + '/plopfile.js');
require('plop');
```

Comment: Hi, I did the same thing, it removed the errors. But nothing happens on executing the command, plop does not ask configured questions. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't directly `require` and use plop is that it is a CLI. As a CLI, it does not export anything but uses `process.argv` as its input. So all you really need to do is alter `process.argv` in your script before `require`ing `plop`.

```
process.argv.push('--version');
require('plop');
```

You could then use the built in `--plopfile` argument to point to a specific file that you'd like to run.

Comment: Can you add an example, please?

Comment: @undefined I updated my answer with a much simpler idea that does work.

Comment: I'm trying to do this: process.argv.push('--plopfile ' + __dirname + '/plopfile.js'); but it still doesn't find the plopfile, you have an idea why?

Comment: "--plopfile" and the path need to be pushed onto argv separately.

Answer (score 0):

Since "plop": "^2.7.3",
I found the above not work any more and from https://github.com/plopjs/plop/issues/78
I saw the new solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const {Plop, run} = require('plop');
const argv = require('minimist')(args);

Plop.launch({
    cwd: argv.cwd,
    configPath: argv.plopfile, // changed to `${process.cwd()}/plopfile.js` in my case
    require: argv.require,
    completion: argv.completion
}, run);
```

Answer (score -1):

npm's `scripts` are (except of *start*) always being run like `npm run plop`. 
Usually you define a start command which is normally run like `npm start` and is known by everyone. You can also chain commands there (if you need to run multiple).

Assuming that you want to run plop as first command: If you type `npm start`, it will execute *plop* and afterwards *node index.js*

```
    "scripts":{
        "start": "plop && node index.js"
    },
```

If you want to run something just **once* after npm install, put it into `"postinstall" : "plop"`